# How to store cookies in one place when working with an Internet phone and Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, cookies

how can I make cookies work for the internet with a smartphone and Wi-Fi

class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var webView: WebView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar_FullScreen);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web)

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
    val settings: WebSettings = webView.settings
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true

    val extras = intent.extras
    if (extras != null)
        webView.loadUrl("${extras.getString(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW)}")

    cookie(extras?.getString(Constants.SEND_LINK_IN_WEB_VIEW)!!)
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

private fun cookie(link: String) {
    val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
    cookieManager.setCookie(link, Constants.COOKIE)
}
```

}

private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
return true
}

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
    view.loadUrl(url)
    return true
}
```

}

I just delete cookies, but I don't define how they work.

Comment: Webviews and contained cookies don't care which Internet connection you use.

Comment: Will they work the same for any of the network?

Comment: The advantage of TCP/IP is that it doesn't matter how you connect to the internet. That is a fundamental property of TCP/IP. HTTP and cookies are built on-top of TCP/IP.